# Object Class Array Casting for a Method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, object

I have an object Student with 4 attributes(age,name,department,surname).
and I create an array of that object like this;

```
Student students[10] blah blah init blah.
```

then i want to use an Student array as argument for a method;

```
-(void) displayStudentInArray : (????) studentarray atIndex: (int) index {.....}
```

'???' are my problem. what do i write there? i ve no idea.

need help. i m new on objective c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using C notation the array should be made like this:

```
NSArray *studentArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: student1, student2, student2, ..., nil];
```

In which case the parameter type will be NSArray

```
-(void) displayStudentInArray : (NSArray *)studentarray atIndex: (int) index {.....}
```

Comment: then how can i access in displayStudentInArray method,

student2's name or attribute.

Comment: `Student studentTwo = [studentArray objectAtIndex:1];` or in general `Student chosenStudent = [studentArray objectAtIndex:index];` also, in the new SDK's you may use `studentArray[index]`

Comment: `-(void) displayStudentInArray:(Student **) studentarray....`
     then i get bad access on next line in that method

    `Student *studentTwo = studentarray[index];`
  ??

Comment: @makin11 I had suggested you use Objective C notation, I don't see a benefit of doing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method for creating arrays is using [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) (or [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you want to modify the array after it is created):

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:student1, student2...];
```

Then your method signature would be:

```
-(void)displayStudentInArray:(NSArray *)studentarray atIndex:(int)index
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are correct, but if you *really* want to use C notation, you just need to add another asterisk to denote a reference to another pointer:

```
- (void)displayStudentInArray:(Student**)studentArray atIndex:(int)index {
    Student* firstStudent = studentArray[1];
    //do what you want with the array
}
```

This is because C arrays are really just pointers to an address in memory. If you wanted a C array for a primitive, it would look like this:

```
int* arrayOfInts = malloc(yourSize * sizeof(int));
```

You have an array of objects, but the idea is just the same. You just add one more asterisk to denote that it's a pointer to a pointer to an object.

```
Student** students = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
Student *tempStudent = (array)[0];
```